# Determining Date Equality in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, equality

I need to find out if two dates the user selects are the same in Javascript. The dates are passed to this function in a String ("xx/xx/xxxx").That is all the granularity I need.

Here is my code:

```
        var valid = true;
    var d1 = new Date($('#datein').val());
    var d2 = new Date($('#dateout').val());
    alert(d1+"\n"+d2);
    if(d1 > d2) {
        alert("Your check out date must be after your check in date.");
        valid = false;
    } else if(d1 == d2) {
        alert("You cannot check out on the same day you check in.");
        valid = false;
    }
```

The javascript alert after converting the dates to objects looks like this:

Tue Jan 25 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

Tue Jan 25 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

The test to determine if date 1 is greater than date 2 works. But using the == or === operators do not change valid to false.

Comment: Have you checked this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338463/how-do-i-do-a-date-comparison-in-javascript. Does it help?

Comment: Tempted to flag this as a duplicate but I think this is a fringe case of the same issue, so I'm not.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The post mentionned (and the accepted answer) are about determining if a date is before or after another, not about equality.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Use the `getTime()` method. It will check the numeric value of the date and it will work for both the greater than/less than checks as well as the equals checks.

EDIT:

```
if (d1.getTime() === d2.getTime())
```

Comment: And the stackoverflow question I posted above shows an example. The questions were identical.

Comment: A simpler way: `if( +d1 == +d2 )`

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want to call `getTime()` just try this:

`(a >= b && a <= b)`

Comment: WTF? Why does that work but the equality operator does not? Where is the sense in that?

Comment: The equality operator checks for reference equality. This means it only returns true if the two variables refer the the same object. If you create two Date objects (`var a = new Date(); var b = new Date();`), they will never be equal.

Comment: Is this not a JS bug or is it a limitation of the equality operator and overloading ability?

Comment: This is what equality does for objects, it checks references.

Comment: @devmiles.com except for string, that are compared by value also, 
`var a ="str1"; var b = "str"+"1"; a == b // true`

Comment: wierd.  You would have thought this would have actually been a place where a seperation between == and === would make sense... Oh wait its javascript.  We dont do sense here!

Comment: @Towa, That works because the >= and <= operators only work on numbers, so they try to convert their operands to numbers. And to convert an object (such as a Date) to a number, JavaScript calls the valueOf() function to get a numeric representation. valueOf() returns the same thing as getTime(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

Answer (score 3):

```
var d1 = new Date($('#datein').val());
var d2 = new Date($('#dateout').val());
```

use two simple ways to check equality

1. `if( d1.toString() === d2.toString())`
2. `if( +d1 === +d2)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the dates directly, you can check that their difference is zero.

```
if (d1 - d2 === 0)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var date = "Wed Oct 07 2015 19:48:08 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)";

var dateOne = new Date(date);
var dateTwo = new Date();

var isEqual = dateOne.getDate() === dateTwo.getDate()
```

this will give you the dates equality

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: This is wrong. The 7th April is not the same as the 7th March.