# Jquery way to hide table rows by date

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a table of data sorted by date. Is there any Jquery plugin or code to hide the rows which has date older than current date?

Date is part of the td element of the row.

P.S: This is a cached page for a long time. So until the cache expires I need client side code to hide the data.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of date? Is it an attribute of an object? is it in the innerhTML of a td? Please expand

Answer (score 1):

You can use either .hide() or .remove() methods to remove specific row within table at client side.

Refer [Hide a table column using jquery in a particular date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853518/hide-a-table-column-using-jquery-in-a-particular-date) and [What is the best way to remove a table row with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170997/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-a-table-row-with-jquery) for additional information.