# How to force kendo-dateinput startdate to not equal enddate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to have the Kendo UI for Angular Dateinput component not allow the startDate to equal the endDate?

I have it styled like this, from the example, but I don't see any ways to restrict the range except for disallowing particular dates. Here all days are allowed, I just need the endDate to always be at minimum, the next day.

Thanks!

```
 <kendo-daterange>
        <label>
            <span class="label">Start</span>
            <kendo-dateinput kendoDateRangeStartInput [(value)]="range.start"></kendo-dateinput>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span class="label">End</span>
            <kendo-dateinput kendoDateRangeEndInput [(value)]="range.end"></kendo-dateinput>
        </label>
        <kendo-daterange-popup [animate]="false"></kendo-daterange-popup>
    </kendo-daterange>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified the Telerik example to make this work. Check out my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pecya2?file=app/app.component.ts).

The idea is using the `valueChange` event emitter of both date inputs. Every time anything changes, both dates are checked and if they are identical, the `range.end` is increased by 1 day.

```html
<kendo-dateinput kendoDateRangeStartInput [(value)]="range.start" (valueChange)="fixEndDate($event)"></kendo-dateinput>
```

```html
<kendo-dateinput kendoDateRangeEndInput [(value)]="range.end" (valueChange)="fixEndDate($event)"></kendo-dateinput>
```

```js
public fixEndDate(e: any) {
      if(this.range.start == null || this.range.end == null) {
        return;
      }

      const startTime = this.range.start.getTime();
      const endTime = this.range.end.getTime();

      if(startTime == endTime) {
        console.log('start and end are the same. Fixing...')
        const dayAfter = new Date(endTime);
        dayAfter.setDate(dayAfter.getDate() + 1);
        this.range.end = dayAfter;
      }
}
```

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587060/determining-date-equality-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) for working with dates in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use max input on start date-input selector and min input on end date-input selector to limit the dates as explained here- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/dateinput/date-ranges/#toc-date-ranges