# JavaScript validation to compare intime and outtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to compare two timing one is start time and second is end time of a selected date that the start time always less than the end time.

And i have tried this but it doesn't worked.

```
startTime="12:00 AM";
endTime ="01:15 PM";

if(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+endTime) < Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+startTime))
{
    alert("End time should exceed the start time");
}
else if(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+endTime) -Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+startTime)==0)
{
    alert("Start time and end time cannot be same");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338463/how-do-i-do-a-date-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: I am testing in the chrome console what you posted and I wonder what is not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var startTime ="12:00 AM";
var endTime   ="01:15 AM";

var date1 = new Date('01/01/2011 '+ startTime); 
var date2 = new Date('01/01/2011 '+ endTime);   

if(date1 > date2)
    alert("End time should exceed the start time");

if(date1.getTime() == date2.getTime())
    alert("Start time and end time cannot be same");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
var startTime ="12:00 AM";
var endTime   ="01:15 AM";


    if(new Date(('01/01/2011 '+endTime)) < new Date(('01/01/2011 '+startTime)))
    {
        alert("End time should exceed the start time");
    }
    else if(new Date(('01/01/2011 '+endTime)) - new Date(('01/01/2011 '+startTime))==0)
    {
        alert("Start time and end time cannot be same");
    }

    console.log(new Date(('01/01/2011 '+endTime)));



    console.log(new Date(('01/01/2011 '+startTime)));
```