# Angularjs ui grid date filter between date range not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular UI grid and I have a date column in which I need to have a filter that filters between start and end date without any date picker

Looking at that example, I tried adding type:'date' to the column definition, however the grid still doesn't filter out rows before the date typed into the 'from...' filter box and after the date typed into the 'to...' filter box.

Anything that I am missing something ?

```
 {  field: 'mixedDate',
    type: 'date',
    width: '15%',
    cellFilter: 'date:"mediumDate"',
    filters:[
    {
     condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
     placeholder: 'greater than'
   },
   {
    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
    placeholder: 'less than'
  }]}
```

I'm looking for functionality like the Age column here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering
except with dates instead of numbers.

Comment: The API doesn't provide a `filerName` property, have you tried removing it?

Comment: yes i have tried by removing that too .. {field: 'mixedDate',
        type: 'date',
        width: '15%',
        cellFilter: 'date:"mediumDate"',
        filters:[
        {
        condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
        placeholder: 'greater than'
      },
      {
        condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
        placeholder: 'less than'
      }]}

Comment: Please check this plunker : i have added the date filter but when i am manually putting the date its not working :   http://plnkr.co/edit/0MIf9QE3LsPFWCWPyDMZ?p=preview

Comment: this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2321 talks about using custom filters

Comment: I created custom date filtering using bootstrap modals with datepickers inside them, if that helps you. See [this previous stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588622/angular-js-ui-grid-custom-date-filter/36946601#36946601).

Comment: i have finally done it ... check my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/0MIf9QE3LsPFWCWPyDMZ?p=preview